# using conditions with window resize eventlistener/handler

Tags: javascript, if-statement, createjs, window-resize

I'm really new to using javascript and working with html so please forgive the noobness, if that's even a word. So, I used Adobe createJS toolkit to display graphics (exportRootTitle) while a load bar shows progress of the preloadJS. I have a handleComplete function which then removes exportRootTitle from the stage and adds another exportRoot (which is the main content).

My problem is I need to have two separate resize functions, one on init and one on the handleComplete function. I tried having two listeners like this:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeTitle, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeMain, false);
```

It doesn't seem to work. So I was thinking maybe there is a way to make the resize function conditional maybe by using "if-else". Maybe something like if handleComplete is fired, the resize function will be for exportRoot but if not yet, it's for exportRootTitle, or something like that. I sort of have an idea but I'm clueless on how to execute.

I'm really not good at explanations so please take a look at the code I have.

```
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

window.addEventListener('resize', resizeTitle, false);

function init() {
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
images = images||{};

var manifest = [
    {src:"images/apple.png", id:"apple"},
    {src:"images/bag.png", id:"bag"},
    {src:"images/car.png", id:"car"},
    {src:"images/drum.png", id:"drum"},
    {src:"images/egg.png", id:"egg"},
    {src:"images/flower.png", id:"flower"},
    {src:"images/gift.png", id:"gift"},
    {src:"images/house.png", id:"house"}
];

var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
loader.loadManifest(manifest);

loader.addEventListener("progress", handleProgress);
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
exportRootTitle = new lib.LoaderTitle();
exportRootTitle.regX = canvas.width/2;
exportRootTitle.regY = canvas.height/2;

var progress = new createjs.Shape();
var progressLine = new createjs.Shape();

progressLine.graphics.setStrokeStyle(2).beginStroke("#CCCCCC").drawRect(175,349,550,10);

function handleProgress(event) {
progress.graphics.clear();
progress.graphics.beginFill("#0B9CFD").drawRect(175,349,550*(event.loaded / event.total),10);
exportRootTitle.LoadingInfo.text = ((100*(event.loaded / event.total)).toFixed() + "%");
}

exportRootTitle.addChild(progressLine, progress);
stage.addChild(exportRootTitle);
stage.update();
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
resizeTitle();
}

function handleFileLoad(evt) {
if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}

function handleComplete() {
stage.removeChild(exportRootTitle);
exportRoot = new lib.LoaderContent();
exportRoot.regX = canvas.width/2
exportRoot.regY = canvas.height/2
stage.addChild(exportRoot);
stage.update();
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}

function resizeTitle() {
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;         

exportRootTitle.x = canvas.width/2;
exportRootTitle.y = canvas.height/2;

var adjustTitle = (window.innerHeight/600)*1;
exportRootTitle.scaleX = exportRootTitle.scaleY = adjustTitle;
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who will try to help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You can add several event listeners to the same event/element. They will be executed in the order they were attached, except in some older browsers like IE8.

Comment: Damn, I feel so stupid. I actually tried that the first time but it didn't work for some reason but when I tried it again now, for some reason it worked. Maybe I made some sort of error in other parts of the code. Anyways, thank you for responding.

Comment: Always check the browser console for errors when your script doesn't work;  the error may not be where you think it is.